# Using Recursion to compare 2 strings in C

Tags: c, recursion

I am required to write a program that uses recursion to compare 2 strings say S1 and S2 which returns 1 , 0 and -1 for s1 > s2, s1 == s2 and s1 < s2 respectively.

For this assignment that I am tasked, I cannot use any string.h library unfortunately.

I am a beginner in recursion and got the hang of dealing with integer / array scenarios. However, when dealing with these strings, I cannot seem to establish the "Terminating condition" and the "Recursive condition" and I seek everyone's kind guidance on this matter.

The main body is provided as a template by my professor so there really isn't anything I can do to edit this portion of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_VALUE 100

int rStrcmp(char *s1, char *s2);

int main()
{
 char source[40], target[40], *p;
 int result = INIT_VALUE;

 printf("Enter a source string: \n");
 fgets(source, 40, stdin);
 if (p=strchr(source,'\n')) *p = '\0';

 printf("Enter a target string: \n");
 fgets(target, 40, stdin);
 if (p=strchr(target,'\n')) *p = '\0';

 result = rStrcmp(source, target);

 printf("rStrcmp(): %d", result);
 return 0;
}
```

The recursive code that I have written so far:

```
int rStrcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
      // The terminating conditions:

      if (*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0') //  both strings end together
         return 0;
      else if (*s1 == '\0') // s1 ends first (s1 smaller)
         return ‐1;
      else if (*s2 == '\0')  // s2 ends first (s1 larger)
         return 1;
      else if (*s1 < *s2) // ASCII char in s1 < s2 : (s1 smaller)
         return ‐1;
      else if (*s1 > *s2)  // ASCII char in s1 > s2 : (s1 larger)
         return 1;     

      else // recursive condition
    {
       rStrcmp(s1+1,s2+1) // moves the address to point to the next char 
    }
}
```

I think I roughly know what my mistake is, that is I am comparing the entire string in the address instead of the individual characters. Is there anyway I could write the program so that I am comparing each characters in both strings?

Seeking everyone's kind guidance on this matter. I can solve this using iteration easily but I have to solve it using recursion and I can't really understand recursion with strings.

EDIT:
This program can compile and run. However, when I input test cases such as:

s1 = abc123
s2 = abc123f

The output returns a 1. Which should actually be a -1 instead.

or

s1 = abc123
s2 = abcdef

The output returns a 1. Which should actually be a -1 as well since the character '1' in s1 has a lower ASCII value than 'd' in s2.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Tip: If you're calling an explicit `return` inside an `if`, then by definition everything past that point is an `else`, so you can omit that.

Comment: `'\0'` == `0`. And all the characters in string are usually positive (or use unsigned char * for string.). So, you can get rid of all the `'\0'` checks. When string ends, you will compare `\0` (== `0`) with `'ch'` from other string where `ch` > 0.

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining at you about the problem. What does your function *return* in the `else` case?

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger to see where that function might be going awry?

Comment: There's really only one thing missing... "return " in front of your recursive call. Use: `return rStrcmp(s1+1,s2+1);`

Comment: several conditions seems to be going well such as if s1 == s2, i receive a 0. The problem is with getting a s1 < s2, I can never seem to get a -1.

Comment: Please show whole program and the one you tried using iterative method.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I have noted down all your inputs and guidance

1) With return statement, else if is redundant.
2) '\0' == 0, therefore 0 will do

Main problem: Missing return for my recursive condition since the missing return means that no value is returned back to the "top" after my termianting condition is satisfied at the "bottom".

Moreover, *s1 and *s2 does indeed compare characters instead of entire string in the address so I was lacking in my understanding in that matter. I have since tested out in an online compiler to deepen my understanding. Thanks everyone!

Comment: [In case you're curious](https://pastebin.com/0eKXDSQY).

Comment: Why exactly would you write code like this? Using a loop was too fast, too readable, too safe? Start by getting rid of the recursion then fix things from there.

Comment: @Lundin 
Hi Lundin, I agree with you. Unfortunately, this was for my school assignment and I have to use recursion to show the Professor that I understood recursion. Of course, using loop would have been so much easier, I agree with you wholeheartedly. Have a nice day.

Comment: Ask your professor _why_ you need to understand how to write slow, dangerous, complex and inefficient code. Most programming classes have _way_ too much focus on recursion, without even mentioning it is the wrong tool in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you give us was not the one you really use, since it doesn't compile, a `;` is missing. I guess it was present after the recursive `rStrcmp` call.

You should activate warning on you compiler, you'll find that

> `In function ‘rStrcmp’: .code.tio.c:60:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }`

In fact, in function `rStrcmp`, the recursive line should be:

```
...
    else // recursive condition
    {
       return rStrcmp(s1+1,s2+1); /* the return was missing here */
    }
...
```

And as pointed in comments, you can simplify your code by removing the `else` since after a return, you're no longer in the function:

```
int rStrcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    // The terminating conditions:
    if (*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0') //  both strings end together
        return 0;
    if (*s1 == '\0') // s1 ends first (s1 smaller)
        return ‐1;
    if (*s2 == '\0')  // s2 ends first (s1 larger)
        return 1;
    if (*s1 < *s2) // ASCII char in s1 < s2 : (s1 smaller)
        return ‐1;
    if (*s1 > *s2)  // ASCII char in s1 > s2 : (s1 larger)
        return 1;     
    // recursive condition
    return rStrcmp(s1+1,s2+1); // moves the address to point to the next char 
}
```

Last move, you could add some formatting information in `main` function to have a nicer output:

```
result = rStrcmp(source, target);

printf("rStrcmp(): %d\n", result);

printf("'%s' %c '%s'\n", source, result == 0 ? '=' : result < 0 ? '<' : '>' , target);
```

Comment: Hello Mathieu, Apologies for the missing ;, it must have been due to the copy and pasting that I missed it out. Apologize for that. 

It works on codeblocks now but previously I was using another compiler from my school and it still isn't working. There must be some issue with that. Thanks for the answer!